# Using cron to open URL in OS X

Tags: macos, cron

I'm trying to open a website URL using terminal in my mac however it is showing command not found.
This is what I'm using.

```
 * 6 * * * /usr/bin/curl -s http://www.website.com > /dev/null
```

Why isn't it working? Help please.

Comment: Did you wait till 6 a.m.? Where does it show `command not found`? What is the output of `which curl`? Try changing `/dev/null` to `/tmp/FreddyFrog.txt` and set the command to fire every minute (change `6` to asterisk) and then look in `/tmp`.

Comment: No! I put 6 to show what I'm trying to achieve, lol. Anyway, I figured it out eventually... I forgot to do `crontab -e` at the beginning. but... It still doesnt open the URL although I changed `curl` to `open`. Don't worry, I set it to run each minute. I did `crontab -l` to check and it seems to be working fine... hmm what could it be?

Comment: This works on my Mac `* * * * * /usr/bin/open http://www.google.com`

Comment: Not sure how you are trying to edit your crontab either... i.e. what you mean by `forgot to put crontab -e at the beginning`. Normally, to edit your crontab in Terminal, you just type `crontab -e` into Terminal and edit it and save it. To view it, you use `crontab -l`. What do you mean "I forgot to put `crontab -e` at the beginning"? The beginning of what? How did you edit it without doing that?